# I can't specify a new region for cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I changed the location of my cloud functions from "us-central1" to "europe-west1" but I can't change the location of my functions on the client side which is a compulsory step for it to work according to the documentation.

(IDE tells me that no argument is expected on 'functions' when i do:

```
firebase.initializeApp(config).functions("europe-west1");
```

As an attempt to solve my problem I updated the three dependancies below with no result.

firebase-tools@latest
firebase-functions@latest 
firebase-admin@latest

The problem is still here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to fix my situation, by reinstalling ionic.

Plus `.functions("europe-west1")` has to be put on every call, not only in `app.module.ts`

Answer (score 6):

You should visit the following documentation page.

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#modify-region
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations

### client side

Use firebase.app.App.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.app.App#functions

Not admin.app.App. The firebase-admin only use on the server side.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.app.App

Set the specified regions for a client app.

```
var firebase = require("firebase/app");
require("firebase/functions");
var config = {
  // ...
};
firebase.initializeApp(config).;
var functions = firebase.app().functions('europe-west1');
```

### server side(Cloud Functions)

Set the specified regions for each function.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 
exports.webhookEurope = functions
    .region('europe-west1')
    .https.onRequest((req, res) => {
        res.send("Hello");
    });
```

> If you are changing the specified regions for a function that's handling production traffic, you can prevent event loss by performing these steps in order:
>
> 1. Rename the function, and change its region or regions as desired.
> 2. Deploy the renamed function, which results in temporarily running the same code in both sets of regions.
> 3. Delete the previous function.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I've went through all the documentation as stated in my question, the problem is on my IDE's end, I can't make it work.

Answer (score 1):

With Typescript, you set the region like this:

`export const myFunction = functions.region("europe-west2").firestore.document("users/{userId}")`

Answer (score 0):

Got it working this way!

```
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  async signup(provider, info) {
    if (!this.isValid) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      switch (provider) {
        case this.EMAIL:
          return await firebaseAuth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            info.email,
            info.password
          ).then(authUser => {
            const addUser = firebaseApp.functions('europe-west1').httpsCallable('addUser');
            addUser({email: info.email,
              name: info.name})
              return authUser
          })
        default:
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  }
```